# PigLatin in PHP eroor

Tags: php

```
function PigLatin($sentence)
{
    $vowelSufix = "way";
    $consonantSufix = "ay";
    $vowelArray = array('a','e','o','u','i');
    $finalword;

    $wordArray = explode(' ', $sentence);
    foreach ($wordArray as $value)
    {
        $word = $value;
        $consonant = $word[0];

        if (in_array($word[0], $vowelArray)) 
        {
            $finalword = substr($word, 1). $word[0]. $vowelSufix. "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            for ($i=1; $i <strlen($word) ; $i++) 
            {
                if (in_array($word[$i], $vowelArray)) 
                {
                    $finalword = substr($word, $i). $consonant. $consonantSufix . "<br />"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $consonant .= $word[$i];
                }
            }
        }
        if ($finalword[0] == $finalword[1]) 
        {
            return substr($finalword, 1);
        }
        $finalword .= $finalword;
    }
    var_dump($wordArray);
}
```

So basicly it is giveing me the follow errors "Uninitialized string offset".I know this error comes because i am useing the arrays not proberly but i am stuck, Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is a "PigLatin"?

Comment: Surely the notice came with a line number?

Comment: @arkascha http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin

Comment: @arkascha Ouyay ouldcay useway [Ooglegay](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=pig+latin) irstfay :)

Comment: What a fun PigLatin must be then. I am out.

Comment: It's a children's game.

Comment: It's how I come up with all my passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't handle the case where `$word` is empty, which will happen if you have two spaces in a row in the sentence.  If `$word` is an empty string, `$word[0]` will get the error you reported, because there is no such character in the string.

Change the loop to:

```
foreach ($wordArray as $word)
{
    if ($word === '') {
        continue;
    }
```

This will skip empty words. Note also that you don't need separate variables `$value` and `$word`.